# Падает коннект к БД

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat, heroku

Делаю проект на heroku (бесплатный аккаунт). Использую *Sping + Hibernate + MySQL*. Как только захожу на сайт - все работает отлично, но если не обращаюсь к БД в течение нескольких секунд  - они падают и страницы, обращающиеся к БД, выдают ошибку. В чем может быть проблема? Когда я запускаю приложение локально с идеи и подключаюсь к этой же БД - все работает отлично.

Может быть, у меня не правильно настроен persistance.хml? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне настроить автореконнект или увеличить таймаут, или что там еще можно сделать???

Полное сообщение об ошибке можно увидеть нажав на кнопку "Поиск" (только при заходе на сайт нужно обождать меньше минуты: https://kiev-lease.herokuapp.com

Мой persistance.хml (закомментированный код - то, что пробовал сам)

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="FlatsJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com:3306/heroku_a2736c1ec063973?reconnect=true"/>-->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com:3306/heroku_a2736c1ec063973?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="b73b29b287469f" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="4e7a84e0" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="280"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>-->



        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.autoCommitOnClose" value="false"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout"-->
                  <!--value="60"/>-->

        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="1800"/>-->
        <!--<property name="c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="1810"/>-->


    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```